# is there better design for login validation in codeigniter ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm try to convert my website to codeigniter framework
i'm a newbie here, and afraid to make some stupid design .
is there any better suggestion?

thanks you all , in advance.

the below image is  my old design
[image]

the below image is  my new design for ci . 
(is it any better suggestion ? )
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken , codeIgniter framework supports filters.
In your case , `beforeFilter` - before the controller is loaded the code in the
beforeFilter function will be used.

Write there a "is_logged" check , if so , no problem (continue to load the controller),
otherwise , call a "Please login" function (with a login form of course)